# GCC, C: Finding out name of default warnings for use in #pragma ignore

Tags: c, gcc, warnings

I've learned that I can put

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "<warning>"
```

to the top of a source file in order to suppress warnings related to this particular source file. However, it seems that some  names are not specific enough. For example,

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wwrite-strings"
```

does not prevent gcc (4.7.2) from displaying warning messages whose exact names are not given, instead, these messages are followed only by [enabled by default]. I guess I need to know the correct warning names so I can use them in the `#pragma` line. I've tried

```
-fdiagnostics-show-option,
```

but the warnings are then still displayed as [enabled by default].

Is there any way to identiy these warnings or to alternatively suppress warnings related to a specific source file?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I believe that the correct option to use is `-Wno-write-strings`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this is a compiler option that disables all corresponding warnings globally. What I wanted to do is disable only warnings that are caused by certain source files. That's why I tried the `#pragma` approach. But thank you anyway!

Answer (score 2):

You have to push and pop diagnostic states.  Like this:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-function"
    /* ignoring warning */

    int unused_function( void ) {
         return 1337;
    }
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Comment: So I did put all the functions of my source file between the pragmas as shown by you, with `-Wwrite-strings`. Still, it does not suppress the warnings coming from this file which are labelled `enabled by default`.

Comment: Can you share more information about what your gcc command line looks like (i.e. -Wall, -pedantic, et cetera)?  What are the exact warnings you are getting?

Comment: I used `-pedantic -Wall -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings`. If I don't do anything, I get warnings labelled with `-Wshadow`, `-Wunused-variable`, `-Wimplicit-function-declaration` and `enabled by default`. Putting `#pragma GCC diagnostic igonred "<warning label>"` to the top of the relevant source files, I can get rid of the first three warning types, but I don't know how to deal with the `enabled by default` warnings coming from those source files.