# how to disable this particular warning

Tags: c, gcc, warnings

This simple code:

```
#define WIDTH 500.5
#define NB 23.2

int x[(int)(WIDTH/NB)];
```

gives me a warning:

```
prog.c:4:1: warning: variably modified 'x' at file scope [enabled by default]
```

If I set `#define WIDTH 500` and `#define NB 23`, the warning disappears.

Passing a float value for `WIDTH` macro forces evaluation by the compiler and thus issues a warning because array has not a constant size.

The preprocessed C code looks like `int x[(int)(500.5/23.2)];`, whereas `int x[(int)(500/23)];` is OK for the compiler (value is already constant integer)

I would like to find a way either

- to ignore this particular warning (but leaving the others so I can enable `-Werror`: seems that is a lost cause: [GCC, C: Finding out name of default warnings for use in #pragma ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997634/gcc-c-finding-out-name-of-default-warnings-for-use-in-pragma-ignore)
- fix the code so it does what I want without issuing warnings.
- force the pre-processor to perform the computation as integer

Funny thing: compiling with `g++` I don't have the warning whereas I read here that variable length arrays are not officially supported in C++, only in C99. But that's not an option for me, since I need to stick to C.

Comment: preprocessor does no calculation on 500/23 - its compiler task

Comment: yes, seen afterwards, but it works. The compiler sees it's an integer constant. With floats, even cast into integers it does not.

Comment: An interestinng thing. If you first cast floats to an int - gcc does not complain

Comment: A simple dirty work-around would be `int x[(int)((int)WIDTH+((int)NB+1))/(int)NB];` - Might spoil a few bytes, but interestingly gets rid of the warning, and allocates (possibly some more than enough) ints

Comment: @tofro: nice!!! could even be adjusted as `int x[((int)WIDTH+1)/(int)NB];` since `((int)WIDTH+1) > WIDTH` and dividing by something smaller than NB also works.

Comment: @tofro: 1) It doesn't spoil anything (but a neglegibble part of compile-time) by definition, because _constant-expressions_ are guaranteed to be evaluated at complie-time. 2) The final cast is unnecessary. Never use casts without good reason and if you don't exactly know their implications!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: That's what "not related" means. Btw: `WIDTH + 1` will casue problems if there is no fraction, unless you always want one more (or can tolerate it)..

Comment: yes, exactly. That's not an issue to allocate one more element (more memory is probably wasted somewhere else in this code :)). That's an issue to allocate not enough elements.

Comment: I still prefer to use correct array dimensions. Over-allocation "just to make sure" is imo bad design. I'd recommend to have 1 or two macros for this constant conversion, possibly parametrise the integer type. As all has to be constant, there is no problem with multiple evaluation, so you could use the conditional operator. Just had to figure out how to do the rounding without preceeding calculation _scratches his head_

Comment: of course. The code isn't mine, I just wanted to turn off this warning without too many changes so I could install `-Werror` in the build chain.

Comment: @Olaf I think you are being too strict here. I don't consider using integer arithmetic to calculate array sizes "Over-allocation just to make sure". But am with you in lots of other cases. Rounding up integer fractions in order to make sure we have enough array elements for all possible values of `WIDTH` and `NB` (in case someone wants to change them later) is a legit safety measure.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: If absolutely necessary, I'm fine with disabling warnings. Howeverr, disabling _errors_ is a different beast. In the case shown, I'm not sure hwo the compiler is supposed to determine the array dimension. It could very well be there is no way to get from the float value to an int value in its backend.

Comment: @tofro: Not sure where you think I'm too strict. The final cast **is** unnecessary and using `size_t` does not really change the game, it just makes clear one knows what one is doing. Re. the over-allocation: I assume you never programed embedded systems, expecially with very limites memory resources, e.g. with 64 or 128 **bytes** RAM (although even with e.g. 64GiB RAM.you could run into trouble, if the `+1` results in some GiB more RAM usage). Briefly: it depends.

Comment: @Olaf I actually meant the over-allocation. With rounding too early, you could easily allocate some bytes short, which is way worse than everything else, even on embedded systems. I'm not saying I find it reasonable to base array sizes on floats, but in this case, it makes sense to round up rather than down. (because code accessing the array might as well round upwards)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could ensure that a normal array (non VLA) is created like this:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wpedantic"
enum{ARRAY_DIMENSION_OF_x = (int)(WIDTH/NB)};
int x[ARRAY_DIMENSION_OF_x];
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

This compiles without warning in gcc and clang in C mode and with a `old-style cast to 'int'` warning in C++ mode.

One could also hide the creation of the enum within a macro:

```
/* ================= define MAKE_CONST_INT() macro ================= */
#ifdef __cplusplus
     template<class T> struct make_const_int_helper{static T t;};
#    define MAKE_CONST_INT(x) (sizeof(*(make_const_int_helper<char (*)[int((x)+0L)]>::t)))  /* +0L avoids "useless cast" warning*/
#else
#    define EVALUATE_TO_0(type) (0*__builtin_types_compatible_p(type,int))
#    define EVALUATE_TO_0_PRAGMA(x) EVALUATE_TO_0(struct{int dummy; _Pragma(x)})

#    define EVALUATE_TO_0_START_DISABLE_WARNINGS                                \
        ( EVALUATE_TO_0_PRAGMA("GCC diagnostic push")                           \
        + EVALUATE_TO_0_PRAGMA("GCC diagnostic ignored \"-Wpedantic\"")         \
        + EVALUATE_TO_0_PRAGMA("GCC diagnostic ignored \"-Wc++-compat\"") )
#    define EVALUATE_TO_0_END_DISABLE_WARNINGS \
        EVALUATE_TO_0_PRAGMA("GCC diagnostic pop")

#    define MAKE_CONST_INT(x) MAKE_CONST_INT_HELPER2(x,__LINE__,__COUNTER__)
#    define MAKE_CONST_INT_HELPER2(x,line,counter) MAKE_CONST_INT_HELPER(x,line,counter)
#    define MAKE_CONST_INT_HELPER(x,line,counter)                                   \
        ( EVALUATE_TO_0_START_DISABLE_WARNINGS                                      \
        + EVALUATE_TO_0(enum{ INT_CONSTANT_##counter##_AT_LINE_##line = (int)(x) }) \
        + INT_CONSTANT_##counter##_AT_LINE_##line                                   \
        + EVALUATE_TO_0_END_DISABLE_WARNINGS)
#endif





/* ================= test MAKE_CONST_INT() macro ================= */
#define WIDTH 500.5
#define NB 23.2
extern int x[MAKE_CONST_INT(WIDTH/NB)];
```

This compiles without warning in gcc and clang in C and in C++ mode.

The structs with the int dummy members are only necessary to get a place where gcc accepts a `_Pragma("GCC diagnostic ....")` pragma.

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/zEMs35E1o)

---

[Extended implementation](https://godbolt.org/z/9YTd35P8T) that works for MSVC, gcc, clang and icc, but still won't compile on really picky compilers:

```
/* ================= define MAKE_CONST_INT() macro ================= */
#ifdef __cplusplus
#    if defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__clang__)
 #       pragma GCC diagnostic push
 #       pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wtemplates"
#    endif
    template<class T> struct make_const_int_helper{static T t;};
#    if defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__clang__)
 #       pragma GCC diagnostic pop
#    endif
#    define MAKE_CONST_INT(x) (sizeof(*(make_const_int_helper<char (*)[int((x)+0L)]>::t)))  /* +0L avoids "useless cast" warning*/
#else
#    if defined(__GNUC__)
#        define EVALUATE_TO_0(type) (0*__builtin_types_compatible_p(type,int))
#        define EVALUATE_TO_0_PRAGMA(x) EVALUATE_TO_0(struct{int dummy; _Pragma(x)})
#        define EVALUATE_TO_0_START_DISABLE_WARNINGS                                \
            ( EVALUATE_TO_0_PRAGMA("GCC diagnostic push")                           \
            + EVALUATE_TO_0_PRAGMA("GCC diagnostic ignored \"-Wpedantic\"")         \
            + EVALUATE_TO_0_PRAGMA("GCC diagnostic ignored \"-Wc++-compat\"") )
#        define EVALUATE_TO_0_END_DISABLE_WARNINGS \
            EVALUATE_TO_0_PRAGMA("GCC diagnostic pop")                       
#    else
#        define EVALUATE_TO_0(type) (0*sizeof(type))
#        if defined(_MSC_VER)
#            define EVALUATE_TO_0_START_DISABLE_WARNINGS \
                (0 __pragma(warning( push )) __pragma(warning(disable:4116)))
#            define EVALUATE_TO_0_END_DISABLE_WARNINGS (0 __pragma(warning( pop )) )
#        else
#            define EVALUATE_TO_0_START_DISABLE_WARNINGS 0  /*other compilers will not disable warning*/
#            define EVALUATE_TO_0_END_DISABLE_WARNINGS 0
#        endif
#    endif
#    define MAKE_CONST_INT(x) MAKE_CONST_INT_HELPER2(x,__LINE__,__COUNTER__)
#    define MAKE_CONST_INT_HELPER2(x,line,counter) MAKE_CONST_INT_HELPER(x,line,counter)
#    define MAKE_CONST_INT_HELPER(x,line,counter)                                   \
        ( EVALUATE_TO_0_START_DISABLE_WARNINGS                                      \
        + EVALUATE_TO_0(enum{ INT_CONSTANT_##counter##_AT_LINE_##line = (int)(x) }) \
        + INT_CONSTANT_##counter##_AT_LINE_##line                                   \
        + EVALUATE_TO_0_END_DISABLE_WARNINGS)
#endif



/* ================= test MAKE_CONST_INT() macro ================= */
#define WIDTH 500.5
#define NB 23.2
extern int x[MAKE_CONST_INT(WIDTH/NB)];
```

Answer (score 3):

It just violates the standard:

> **Integer constant expression**
>
> An integer constant expression is an
> expression that consists only of operators other than assignment,
> increment, decrement, function-call, or comma, except that cast
> operators can only cast arithmetic types to integer types, integer
> constants, enumeration constants, character constants, **floating
> constants, but only if they are immediately used as operands of casts
> to integer type**

And further:

> The following contexts require expressions that are known as integer
> constant expressions':
>
> ...
>
> - The index in an array designator (since C99)

Comment: Recommend either adding a citation and /or using the C11 standard which differs a bit.

Answer (score -1):

Here one example from [GNU GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html) that can help you:

```
  #pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wuninitialized"
    foo(a);                       /* error is given for this one */
  #pragma GCC diagnostic push
  #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wuninitialized"
    foo(b);                       /* no diagnostic for this one */
  #pragma GCC diagnostic pop
    foo(c);                       /* error is given for this one */
  #pragma GCC diagnostic pop
    foo(d);                       /* depends on command-line options */
```

Comment: Ok but in my particular case what would be the keyword: `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wsomething???"
int x[(int)(WIDTH/NB)];
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop` since there's no indication on how to suppress the warning in the warning itself?

Comment: Here the full list of options that you can use: [gcc-list](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html). I suppose that you need all the following options: **-Wconversion**, **-Wformat** and **-Wtraditional**. Check in the attached list.

Comment: so much for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997634/gcc-c-finding-out-name-of-default-warnings-for-use-in-pragma-ignore

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. It just gives advice how to use the error/warning-related pragmas in general. It also does noit solve the problem, because the problem persists. In general it is strongly adviced not do kill the messenger (i.e. silence the diagnostic), but fix the problem at the innermost level possible.